Could a 200m diameter asteroid be put into a graveyard orbit and not be noticed by people on the ground?
So, there’s a secret space station—code named Anvil—that is run by a secret military organization that was formed to provide a rapid response team against national/global threats. They launched a payload of bots that turned the asteroid into a habitable station, which they then brought to a graveyard orbit (~36,000 km).
Apart from rare instances in which a transport docks with them, there is no venting of gasses. The albedo is between .07 and .1, and the asteroid surface is similar to a chondrite asteroid (clay and silicates), with metal making up most of the interior—sourced from other asteroids.
Nations and militaries are not actively searching for this, but could it be accidentally spotted by current technologies?

The "graveyard orbits" at ~36000 km and zero inclination are called such because that's where we dispose of geostationary satellites. Basically the only significance of that orbit is that it is very close to geostationary orbit. Considering the extreme importance of geostationary satellites, you'd be placing your station in an area that is under constant monitoring for potential threats to those satellites. You're basically putting up a flashing neon sign with an arrow saying "OVER HERE!".

Yes, OP you may misunderstand "graveyard orbits" - but yes, it sounds awesome in fiction!

Answering your question, it's quite easy to just SEE (!) normal; one or two foot satellites in some cases. A 500 foot satellite would be blatant.

@ChristopherJamesHuff, I never knew there was a zero inclination. Would putting it at, say, a 70 degree inclination help significantly?

@BlueSkinandGlowingRedEyes that would be less likely to cross the field of view of any given telescope monitoring satellites near GEO, though it'll still do so occasionally. You'll still need to deal with it being obviously visible to light and radar (and glaringly obvious in thermal), but not having it cruise through the field of view of every telescope watching GEO satellites will certainly help.

Any asteroid changing orbit will become an object of very keen interest of multiple governments in the world. It will be monitored 24/7. A quick response team waiting in zero gravity will get useless rather fast. It would need regular resupply flights. After the first quick response mission there will be no secrecy left. Getting to and from an orbit is a very bright show. Using large ballistic missiles or underwater bases for this purpose makes much more sense.

A "quick response team" in an inclined near-GEO orbit is also going to be too far away to actually respond quickly...it'll take hours for Earth to rotate into position and hours more for them to actually get back.

@ChristopherJamesHuff, my rapid response team was more of, hey, aliens just showed up and we need to kick their butts (or anatomical equivalents), and less of human interaction. Probably could have put that in, but I thought it was an unnecessary detail

If they don't show up in an orbit that's closely aligned, your team likely won't have the delta-v to respond at all. Really, the best you can hope for is that they land immediately, which reduces things to the same problem of reaching Earth. The fastest starting point for unexpectedly reaching any arbitrary orbit would likely be Earth's surface.

Uhm, how realistic does this all need to be? If aliens showed up, they are going to deploy guided kinetic energy projectiles before slowing down from interstellar speeds. Unless, they want to secretly visit. Or there is some magic warp technology which would allow for magic cloak technology.

Forget about telescopes for a minute. Anvil's first worry is sunlight visibility to the naked eye. The sun will light them up. Based on this table, an 0.2 km asteroid at 1 AU would have a visual magnitude around 19, because of the reflected sunlight. The Anvil station is 5000 times closer, so would be reflecting 25 million times more sunlight at Earth. Every factor of 100 more sunlight reduces the magnitude by 6, which would put Anvil at a visual magnitude of about 19 - 5*log_100 (25e6) = 0.5, which would make it plainly visible to the naked eye, similar to Mars or Saturn.
But we do have ultra-black paint. Vantablack absorbs more than 99% of light. Painting the station with that would be enough to increase visual magnitude from 0.5 to 5.5. Unfortunately, that's still barely visible to the naked eye.
But there is another trick. The station could be shaped in such a way that the sunlight only hits the back of it as seen from Earth. This would require putting a big, properly shaped shroud over the asteroid. Like this:

From Earth, the illuminated yellow side of the station is not visible. Even a powerful optical telescope won't see anything.
However, as the station orbits, the angle needed to keep Earthlings from seeing anything will change. The shroud will need to be rotated around the asteroid to keep up. This could be possible.
But if the station ever finds itself on the opposite side of Earth from the Sun, then it can't pull this trick anymore; however it turns, people on Earth can see. Fortunately, there is a solution: put the station in a sun-synchronous orbit. This way, the station will never be on the opposite side of Earth from the Sun.
But, oops, sun-synchronous orbits aren't at 27,000 km. They're much lower. The TRACE satellite orbited in a dawn-dusk sun-synchronous orbit, which is about what we'd want to keep Anvil from being on the opposite side of the Earth. Unfortunately, TRACE's altitude was between 520 km and 547.2 km. At such a low altitude Anvil would be spotted immediately by any number of satellites and space monitoring systems.
There's also the issue of Earth-based radar telescopes, which could be solvable if you make Anvil's shroud radar-reflective and arrange so it reflects the radar pulses away from Earth. There's the issue of visible rocket burns to put Anvil in its orbit and to shuttle things to and from Anvil, which is probably not solvable without some new type of rocket drive.
But none of that matters if you can't even stop the average guy on the ground from seeing your "secret" station when he looks up at night!

How do you keep the shroud from being visible?

This object would occlude things. Stars, planets and the sun.

every factor 100 changes magnitude by 5 (not 6)

@JamesK Thanks, fixed.

@Michael  We would only see its reflected sunlight.  With the shape described, the reflections would all be away from Earth and the remainder of the station would be in shadow.  That said, radar and microwave reflections and infrared emissions would still be a concern.


What if the thing orbits Earth on a plane perpendicular to the Sun-Earth axis? Yes I know, it requires orbital inclination change, and not even a little, but for some months, I think it could work. 2. What if it is using an array of near-perfect mirrors (near perfect mirror example: using total reflection of anything with high optical density) 3. What if it is in L1 Lagrange point (sun-synchronous orbit variant). It is very far away, 2million km.


I think, Anvil needs stealth technology from the USA fighter aircrafts, and also proper cooling to cover its infrared radiation. It would still cover things, but... another problem, and that is unavoidable: it will be visible from the geosynchronous satellites in simple visible light.

Radar exists, and has existed for three quarters of the century. A 200 meters wide target on an equatorial orbit will be detected very very quickly. If the thing is not on an equatorial orbit it might take some time, but it will still be detected in a matter of days, by multiple competing powers.
Oh yes, the relevant space forces are actively looking for satellites which are where no satellite ought to be. A biggg juicy target on a near-Earth orbit has no hope of escaping detection.
Then the mass media will explode into a frothing frenzy.
P.S. In practice the asteroid would be observed looong before it makes it to the near-Earth orbit. Several space agencies are on the lookout for asteroids coming anywhere near Earth. Not to mention the blindingly luminous engine burns required for the massive spacecraft to enter orbit around Earth and then to circularize it.

Though it's true radar telescopes can easily spot such an object normally, it's possible the object could be covered in angular surfaces like a stealth bomber, which would drastically reduce its radar cross section. In fact, it could do this better than a stealth bomber because aerodynamics are not a concern. Spotting something with the radar cross section of a toaster at 36k km is more of a challenge.

This mentions the most important part - even if the asteroid is completely invisible to radar, there is zero chance that the burns required to put it in its new orbit would go unnoticed.

@causative - At 200m diameter, it's also much, much larger than a stealth bomber.  JAXA's SSA system monitors objects 1m in diameter at that range, using optical, thermal and radar.

@jdunlop SSA uses radar only at distances up to 1000 km. At 27,000 km it only has an optical telescope. See https://global.jaxa.jp/projects/ssa/index.html

Can't you just give it a well calculated push at the start and then let gravity/inertia do the rest? That way you don't need to burn a few nukes worth of fuel near earth.

@Vilx-: No. Without engines or some other spectacular means of braking nothing can enter orbit around anything else, because in the absence of dissipative forces mechanics is completely time reversible. If it could be possible to come from the asteroid belt and enter orbit around Earth without consuming fuel, then it would also be possible to go from Earh orbit to the asteroid belt without consuming fuel.

@AlexP it is possible to have an inert object undergo ballistic capture... there are some gas giant moons which are believed to be captured asteroids or minor planets. If you could arrange for the asteroid to arrive at Earth on a transfer orbit with a relative velocity of under 2 km/s, you could use a gravitational assist from the moon to trap it in the Earth's sphere of influence without firing a rocket. I don't think that helps the overall plausibility of the OP, however.

(injection into a specific orbit close to Earth, rather than sitting in cislunar space, remains problematic, but at least you could use long-duration low-thrust propulsion mechanisms rather than needing to nuke it into place)

A problem with this is how often we have asteroids sneak up on us. A few that I found with a fast search: 2024-2000 2024 cy1, 2022 OE2, 2023 NT1. 2023 NT1 is described as "skyscraper sized" and wasn't noticed until 2 days after it passed us. The sky is really really big. If you put radar absorbing material on it, make it dim, and have it approach from the sun side you can really minimize the risks of detection by a lot.

While radar exists, also radar covering technology exists and it could be used on a space station just like on an USA battle aircraft. There might be a problem of its infrared radiation, that could be solved by cooling.

Others have made good suggestions about ways to minimize the albedo to make it less visible, but it's hard to completely remove it.
I think that what you could do is instead of trying to hide it completely, you pull a sleight of hand and let them know there is something there, but not what they think.
For instance, I've heard several people give pitches for space advertising, or space tourism. So you say "we're launching this trial before the olympics to see if it's possible, and we're going to put a space billboard made of a giant mylar sheet that says 'give peace a chance' in orbit for a few weeks before pushing it to a graveyard orbit."
In the meantime you coat your asteroid with radar absorbing material to reduce it's radar cross section, and do what you can to cut down it's reflected sunlight.
The event happens, the billboard is decommissioned to the desired orbit, and you promise to never try it again after the inevitable backlash. Then once the news cycle moves on and people stop thinking about you, you move the asteroid into the same orbit as the billboard, and you can even partially wrap the billboard around the satellite so that even if someone decides to look for it with a telescope they'll only see what they expect to see.
One thing that will help is that space is really big, and we've had a number of real life asteroids sneak up on us.
A few that I found with a fast search: 2024-2000 2024 cy1, 2022 OE2, 2023 NT1.
2023 NT1 is described as "skyscraper sized" and wasn't spotted until 2 days after it passed us.
If you put radar absorbing material on it, make it dim, and maybe have it approach from the sun side you can really minimize the risks of detection by a lot.
The sleight of hand is to just reduce the risk of it being noticed when it's in close orbit to us.

Put it into the L2 Lagrange point of the Earth-Moon-system. A station at L2 would need some fuel for stationkeeping, but it would be hidden behind Luna.

The problem with this is that the moon is three days away, and that's if you're really bookin' it. Hardly a 'rapid response'

@NoName, the flight time depends on delta-V, but yes, hiding comes at a cost.

Frame challenge: what is Anvil's shape?
If it was long and thin, it would be almost invisible when viewed end-on. If it was in an equatorial orbit, pointed towards Earth's centre, then someone in the region of the poles would see it at an angle of 10 degrees. Even then, its cross-section would be small, so it would be hard to spot optically or by radar.
This does not mean that it would not be spotted. Objects in graveyard orbits are routinely monitored from Earth. Perhaps you could attach Anvil to some existing piece of space debris, so it would fit into its shadow. It would still be possible to spot it, but any extra signal would be assumed to be from the original object, perhaps changing its attitude or albedo.
Anvil could get in place by approaching the orbit from the sun.
Conclusion: unlikely but not impossible. Monitoring systems would not expect a long-thin object that shadows a known piece of space debris, so they could be forgiven for not spotting it. But hiding is a poor protection strategy: once it is spotted, the whole game is up.
